# How to serve proper background-image size depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div:

```
<div id="ibanners-home" class="ibanners-wrapper"></div>
```

With the following css:

```
#ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
```

Now the banner loads 1920x500 image for all screens.
I would like to have 3 image versions: 1366x500, 1600x500, 1920x500 that will load depending on the screen resolution.
How do i do that?

Comment: use background-size:cover;

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mediaquery` for this

```
#ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner_1366.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
}

@media (min-width:1366px) { 
    #ibanners-home {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner_1600.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
    }
}   
@media (min-width:1600px) { 
    #ibanners-home {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner_1920.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
    }
}
```

Comment: Super User thank you for your reply, that's exactly what needed.

Comment: Could you explain me what are the pros and cons of putting this style inline vs in css file? 

I was about to put it in our base.css, but than checked how the most optimized site in our niche is doing that,
for some reason they are putting it inline. 

Not in header like you would expect for critical path optimisation, but in body right after the div.

Basically they have main.css in header, and than separate inline css right after div.

Comment: They inline like that: <style>
    .intro {
        background-image: url(/intro_variety_small.jpg);
    }
    &media (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 736px) {
        .intro {
            background-image: url(/intro_variety_medium.jpg);
        }
    }
    &media (max-width: 1365px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
        .intro {
            background-image: url(/intro_variety_large.jpg);
        }
    }
    &media (min-width: 1366px) {
        .intro {
            background-image: url(/intro_variety_extra_large.jpg);
        }
    }
</style>

Comment: I've replaced AT with &, cause AT is not allowed in comments.

Comment: You can't put media query inline

Comment: Maybe inline is not the right word, please comment on the following example: https://www.getyourguide.com/

Comment: Here is the html with css inlined - https://puu.sh/vEmfv/ad5275efb0.png, all other css is in separate files. So i am sure they did that on purpose.

Comment: you can check pro and cons in detailed in following link
https://diablo3blizz.wordpress.com/m1-pros-and-cons-of-internal-external-and-inline-use-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

Use css media queries

```
#ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner1920x500.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media  (max-width: 768px) {
  #ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner1366x500.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
  }
}
@media  (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  #ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner1600x500.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
  }
}
@media  (min-width: 901px) {
  #ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ibanners-home {
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1920) {
    #ibanners-home {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner1920.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
}
@media (min-width: 1600) and (max-width: 1919) {
#ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner1600.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
}
@media (max-width: 1599) {
#ibanners-home {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/images/main-banner1366.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add **`background-size:cover`** or you want your image to be stretch according to container dimension, though your image is not in same dimension  so you need to add **`background-size:100% 100%`**

See the working snippet below:

```css
.banner {
  background: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpaper-pc-background/wallpaper-pc-background-11.jpg);
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
<h1> I am the banner</h1>
</div>
```